# Django "No Module Named URLs" error

Tags: python, django

There are many similar questions posted already, but I've already tried those solutions to no avail.  I'm working through a basic Django tutorial, and here is my code:

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'tango_with_django_project.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^tango_with_django_project/', include('tango_with_django_project.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^rango/', include('rango.urls')), # ADD THIS NEW TUPLE!
)
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Rango says hello world!")
```

From the settings.py file

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'tango_with_django_project.urls'
```

Hope you all can help get me started

Comment: Did you add a urls.py into your app directory for rango? When stating include('rango.urls'), your are telling django to look in the directory rango for the file urls.py.

Comment: Thank you!  That was the issue. 

I did add the urls.py into my app directory for rango, but now I get an error telling me that the current URL didn't match any of the URL patterns in the urls.py file

Comment: Try looking over the urls.py file in the directory. Have you added any urls, similar to my example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say I have a Django project called FailBook, with two apps, posts and links. If I look into FailBook/urls.py, I will find something like

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^posts/', include('posts.urls')), ## Custom url include
    url(r'^links/', include('links.urls')), ## Custom url include
)
```

So then, when you look into the directory structure, you will notice that there are extra two urls.py files

```
FailBook
|-- posts
   |-- models.py
   |-- urls.py
   |-- views.py
   |-- etc.
|-- links
   |-- models.py
   |-- urls.py
   |-- views.py
   |-- etc.

# urls.py file in the posts folder
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from .views import PostListView, PostDetailView

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^posts/', PostListView.as_view()), 
    url(r'^posts/(?P<post_id>\d+)', PostDetailView.as_view()),
)
# where both views are class based views, hence the as_view function call
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by adding urls "similar to your example."  sorry, could you explain it to me further?

Comment: Do you know how to write views and attach them to the urls.py file? If not, read the first few sections of https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/.

Comment: Thanks!  I checked out the Django tutorial and I finally got it

Answer (score 3):

I know this was already solved, but the solutions provided did not help me. When I had this error it was as simple as checking all of the directories that should have had urls.py files.What I discovered was that the urls.py had not been added to the SVN repository that our Django app was pulled from.

I recommend looking in the projectname->projectname->urls.py for all references to app specific urls, and verifying that the urls.py file exists for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue while doing a Pluralsight Django tutorial. Two things I noticed:

1) I was using Django 2.0, and the command url() from Django 1.11 has been replaced with re_path() in 2.0, obtained by importing as follows:

```
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
```

This replaces,

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
```

see this: [Django 2.0 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.0/)
and,

2) I accidentally called the file to be imported from the subfolder, url.py, not urls.py
e.g. rango/url.py not rango/urls.py.

This was probably the main issue, and all flowed smoothly after that fix.