# For loop did't working in view.py Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

in view.py

```
Id = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

for w in Id:
    A = w
    Pending = pending(A)
    data = {     
        'Pending': Pending,

    }
    return render_to_response('dialer_campaign/campaign/list.html', data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def pending(campaign_id):

    A = Campaign_phonebook.objects.values_list('phonebook_id').filter(campaign_id = campaign_id)

    B = Contact.objects.filter(phonebook_id__in=A).count()
    C = Subscriber.objects.filter(campaign_id = campaign_id).exclude(status = 1).count()
    Result = B - C
    return Result
```

When i add manual value instead of A it gives result,but now i want to give value by for loop it is not working.Why ? Can anybody Help me ?

Want changes should i do in templates ?

[image: In image you can see result.it is result when i assign pending(8).I want to get result against loop. Result of every box in pending should be according to value of loop.]

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Please format your code properly!

Comment: tell me where you face difficulty in code ?

Comment: Actually you are overwriting data object.

Answer (score 2):

Take your data object in list and render to the template

Refer following code

```
Id = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
pending_list = []
for w in Id:
    pending = pending(w)
    pending_list.append({'pending': pending})
    return render_to_response('dialer_campaign/campaign/list.html', pending_list, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def pending(campaign_id):
    A = Campaign_phonebook.objects.values_list('phonebook_id').filter(campaign_id = campaign_id)
    B = Contact.objects.filter(phonebook_id__in=A).count()
    C = Subscriber.objects.filter(campaign_id = campaign_id).exclude(status = 1).count()
    Result = B - C
    return Result
```

Use pending_list in your template. In pending_list list you get all the pending objects.

Comment: Great idea. Please tell me what should i have to do in Templates ?

Comment: Use a for loop in your template ``{% for i in pending_list %} {{i.pending}}
{% endfor %}``

Comment: refer [No module name urls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779284/django-no-module-named-urls-error)